# Is it possible to have multiple readers for one step in spring batch?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I need to create a spring batch wherein i need to fetch data from 2 different tables.
This will be the reader part.

The problem is i need to have 2 reader queries. And only one of them will be called based on the condition.
But the writer will be same.
So tasklet becomes same basically.

Can i have 2 readers inside one single step which will be called according to the condition..??

Something like inside the spring batch xml:

```
if (condition)
then reader1
else reader2


...
....
......


<reader1 id=".." class="..">

</reader1>

.....
........

<reader2 id=".." class="..">

</reader2>
```

Comment: `only one of them will be called based on the condition`: What is the condition based on? A job parameter? A system property? Something calculated in a previous step? I see no need to have two readers in your case, this is a matter of configuration IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the conditional control flow patterns Spring Batch offers? I think it could lead to simpler construction and adhere to some of the core patterns spring batch encourages.

You basically program the "condition" that you want a step to be called under. So define two steps, say `step1` which has a reader, processor, writer for one object type and `step2` which has a reader, processor, writer for the other type. Perhaps the writers are shared between types as well. You then can define control flow like so:

```
    @Bean
    public Job myJob() {
        JobBuilder jobBuilder = jobs.get("Spring Batch: conditional steps");
     
        return jobBuilder.start(determineRoute())
                             .on("item1").to(flow1())
                             .on("item2").to(flow2()).end()
                         .build();
                 
    }
```

In the example `determineRoute()` is a tasklet that returns custom ExitStatus values `item1` or `item2` & `flow1` and `flow2` are different flows (or steps) to handle each object.

See here in their docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#conditionalFlow

Edit: you can also do something similar with a `JobExecutionDecider` https://www.baeldung.com/spring-batch-conditional-flow#2-programmatic-branching-withjobexecutiondecider